# Zf 2 ----phpunit no test execute error

Tags: php, phpunit, zend-framework2

I am learning zend 2.0.6, on the initial point. I am getting the following error in phpunit test
PHPUnit 3.7.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\module\Application\test\phpunit

.xml

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 4.25Mb

No tests executed!

My phpunit.xml.dist is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit bootstrap="Bootstrap.php">
 <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="ZendSkeletonApplication">
        <directory>/ApplicationTest</directory>
    </testsuite>
 </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

bootstrap is

```
<?php
 namespace ApplicationTest;//Change this namespace for your test

 use Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory;
 use Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManagerConfig;
 use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
 use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
 use RuntimeException;

 error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
 chdir(__DIR__);

 class Bootstrap
 {
protected static $serviceManager;
protected static $config;
protected static $bootstrap;

public static function init()
{
    // Load the user-defined test configuration file, if it exists; otherwise, load
    if (is_readable(__DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php')) {
        $testConfig = include __DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php';
    } else {
        $testConfig = include __DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php.dist';
    }

    $zf2ModulePaths = array();

    if (isset($testConfig['module_listener_options']['module_paths'])) {
        $modulePaths = $testConfig['module_listener_options']['module_paths'];
        foreach ($modulePaths as $modulePath) {
            if (($path = static::findParentPath($modulePath)) ) {
                $zf2ModulePaths[] = $path;
            }
        }
    }

    $zf2ModulePaths  = implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $zf2ModulePaths) . PATH_SEPARATOR;
    $zf2ModulePaths .= getenv('ZF2_MODULES_TEST_PATHS') ?: (defined('ZF2_MODULES_TEST_PATHS') ? ZF2_MODULES_TEST_PATHS : '');

    static::initAutoloader();

    // use ModuleManager to load this module and it's dependencies
    $baseConfig = array(
        'module_listener_options' => array(
            'module_paths' => explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $zf2ModulePaths),
        ),
    );

    $config = ArrayUtils::merge($baseConfig, $testConfig);

    $serviceManager = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig());
    $serviceManager->setService('ApplicationConfig', $config);
    $serviceManager->get('ModuleManager')->loadModules();

    static::$serviceManager = $serviceManager;
    static::$config = $config;
}

public static function getServiceManager()
{
    return static::$serviceManager;
}

public static function getConfig()
{
    return static::$config;
}

protected static function initAutoloader()
{
    $vendorPath = static::findParentPath('vendor');

    if (is_readable($vendorPath . '/autoload.php')) {
        $loader = include $vendorPath . '/autoload.php';
    } else {
        $zf2Path = getenv('ZF2_PATH') ?: (defined('ZF2_PATH') ? ZF2_PATH : (is_dir($vendorPath . '/ZF2/library') ? $vendorPath . '/ZF2/library' : false));

        if (!$zf2Path) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.');
        }

        include $zf2Path . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';

    }

    AutoloaderFactory::factory(array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'autoregister_zf' => true,
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    ));
}

protected static function findParentPath($path)
{
    $dir = __DIR__;
    $previousDir = '.';
    while (!is_dir($dir . '/' . $path)) {
        $dir = dirname($dir);
        if ($previousDir === $dir) return false;
        $previousDir = $dir;
    }
    return $dir . '/' . $path;
}
}

 Bootstrap::init();
```

TestConfig.php.dist is

```
<?php
    return array(
        'modules' => array(
            'Application',
        ),
        'module_listener_options' => array(
            'config_glob_paths'    => array(
                '../../../config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
            ),
            'module_paths' => array(
                'module',
                'vendor',
            ),
        ),
    );
```

and the thins as in documentation --http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/unit-testing.html
where is mistake,, am i doing wrong somewhere

Answer (score 2):

Remove the leading `/` from

```
<directory>/ApplicationTest</directory>
```

A leading `/` on unix means the root directory, which is not what you want. Even on Windows not.